# Can I put kubernetes in a docker container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm

I've used Docker Swarm - I can put the management and the agents in docker containers. Can I do the same with Kubernetes?
I don't want to pollute my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the master components in Kubernetes run inside of containers.

Due to limitations of Docker, the kubelet agent has been difficult to get running in a container. The Kubernetes folks have been working on this for the last year (see [kubernetes#4869](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4869)), and with Docker 1.10 it looks like it is getting close to working.